# parLapply multiple arguments R

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, raster

I am trying to compute evaporation by `hargreaves` method within the `package SPEI`.This involves using minimum temperature (`TMIN`) and 
maximum temperature (`TMAX`). Parallel computing is my best bet given that `Tmin` and `Tmax` `rasterstacks` have `500,000 cells and 100 layers each`.
`Hargreaves function` takes `Tmin`,`Tmax` and `latitude` at `each grid` as input. The following is my first guess how to go about this:

```
library(SPEI)
# go parallel 
library(parallel)
clust <- makeCluster(detectCores())

#har <- hargreaves(TMIN,TMAX,lat=37.6475) # get evaporation for a station.
```

However, my data is gridded.

`Tmin` and `Tmax` are list, each dataframe in `Tmin` and `Tmax` has a `$latitude` attached to it. In `pet`, `k$d` is Tmin, `k$d` is Tmax (maybe I should provide two arguments in `pet` e.g. `function(k,y)` instead of just `k`?)

```
pet <- function(k) {
  hargreaves(k$d,k$d, k$latitude, na.rm=TRUE)}

# Make library and function available to clust
clusterEvalQ(clust, library(SPEI))
clusterExport(clust, pet)

pet_list <- parLapply(clust, TMIN,TMAX, pet)
```

`parLapply` accepts just one argument. How can I pass `Tmin` and `Tmax` to `parLapply`? 
Is it that my pet function is not correct?

Thanks.

Comment: You might also take a look at `clusterMap` in the same package.

Answer (score 2):

An index could be used to reference a row in a globally defined `data.frame`. I give an example below.

```
library(SPEI)
library(parallel)
```

Define the test list.

```
Tmin <- list(aa = data.frame(a=1:30, b1=runif(30), b2=runif(30), latitude=runif(30)),
  bb = data.frame(a=1:30, b1=runif(30), b2=runif(30), latitude=runif(30)))

Tmax <- list(aa = data.frame(a=1:30, b1=runif(30), b2=runif(30), latitude=runif(30)),
  bb = data.frame(a=1:30, b1=runif(30), b2=runif(30), latitude=runif(30)))
```

Make the cluster

```
clust <- makeCluster(2)
```

This is the re-written function, but we'll test it out on a simpler function.

```
pet1 <- function(ind){
  Tmin[[ind]]$a + Tmax[[ind]]$a
}
```

Call the `SPEI` library and send everything in the workspace to each CPU. This is normally not great form, so forgive me.

```
clusterEvalQ(clust, library(SPEI))
clusterExport(clust, ls())
```

Run the `parLapply` function

```
pet_test <- parLapply(clust, 1:length(Tmin), pet1)
```

*edit*: Edited to account for Tmin and Tmax being lists. The core idea is the same, which is to use an index as the one argument to the `pet` function, and to reference a global variable from within `pet`.

Comment: thanks for providing a timely solution. My `test` are `lists`, Tmin and Tmax. Each dataframe in them has one latitude value. Can you implement `test` as lists pls? Thanks.

Comment: would you mind to implement this approach on my real world problem? I can send you some sample data via a link. I still couldn't get it running. Thanks